# Validity of proof the continuity of the differentiation of the continuous bilinear form

Tags: vector-spaces, multilinear-algebra

Let $E, F, G$ be $3$ normed vector spaces. $B : E \times F \to G$ is a continuous bilinear form. Show that $B$ is differentiable on $E \times F$.

I need to show that: $dB_{(a_1,a_2)}(v_1,v_2) = B(a_1,v_2)+B(a_1,v_2)$

To show its continuity, can I just use the usual way: let $\big((v_1^{(n)},v_2^{(n)})\big)_n$ be a sequence in $E \times F$ which converges to $(v_1,v_2)$ and show that $\displaystyle dB_{(a_1,a_2)}(v_1^{(n)},v_2^{(n)}) \to dB_{(a_1,a_2)}(v_1,v_2)$?

(I just ask for the validity of this approach, NOT how to prove the continuity)

Comment: consider a simpler case: $E\times E\to\Bbb R$

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, unless I'm missing something, that what you need to prove first is that for $(x,y),(h,k)\in E\times F$ you have $B(x+h,y+k)=B(x,y)+dB_{(x,y)}(h,k)+o(||h||+||k||)$ as $(h,k)\to 0$.  This is the general definition of derivative, and note $dB_{(x,y)}\in L(E\times F,G)$.

Because $B$ is bilinear you'll be able to write $B(x+h,y+k)=B(x,y+k)+B(h,y+k)=B(x,y)+B(x,k)+B(h,y)+B(h,k)$.  Because $B$ is continuous you should be able to bound $||B(u,v)||$ in terms of $||u||$ and $||v||$ for any $(u,v)$.

The sequence limit you've written is for sure a way of stating what you have to prove, once you've proven the existence of the derivative, in order to show that the derivative is continuous.